# UITextfield dropdown with floating label

Tags: floating-labels

"I'm looking for Swift libraries that provide both a text field with a floating label and dropdown functionality. Can anyone recommend libraries or suggest approaches to achieve this design in Swift?"[dropdown with floating label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJVba.png)

I tried with some textfiled dropdown libries but in that not having floating label feature.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.